# Strange bland-altman plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics, limit, confidence-interval

Can someone help me interpret this plot? : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXcI8.png)

I want to compare two methods' ability to measure the distance of fracture in mm.

I did a turkey transformation in R to make the residuals normally distributed.

I would say that there is a high systemic bias? Does it seem like one of the methods measures a higher value sometimes and a lower one others?

I think it looks a bit strange and I do not understand it.

This plot is before I computed the transformation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efdf9.png)

And this is my table with limits of agreements:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQMR.png)

Thank you